# How can I access the current kernel via IPython when I open a Jupyter Notebook in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ipython

When  working with Jupyter Notebooks (*.ipynb files) in VSCode I would like to see the Interactive Python prompt after running a cell

It seems that is possible only when working with ad-hoc playbooks (cells delimited by #%% in python files)

How do I do that when I work with Jupyter playbooks ?